# How will I create Lead Generation Audit Report?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, seo-audit, seo-competition-analysis

Need to create a Lead Generation Audit Report for a site. Which elements (Metrics) are important for this Audit Report. Is there any special techniques to create this types of Audit Report or process or follow chart of the Audit Report that I can understand site owner to show this report.

Answer (score 1):

The actual analysis is broken down into five large sections:

- Accessibility
- Indexability
- On-Page Ranking Factors
- Off-Page Ranking Factors
- Competitive Analysis

**Accessibility**. If search engines and users can't access your site, it might as well not exist.

- The **[robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en)** file is used to restrict search engine
  crawlers from accessing sections of your website. Although the file
  is very useful, it's also an easy way to inadvertently block
  crawlers. Manually check the robots.txt file, and make sure it's not 
  restricting access to important sections of your site.
- The **[robots meta tag](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag)** is used to tell search engine crawlers if they are allowed to index a specific page and follow its links.
- **[HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)**. Search engines and users are unable to access your site's content if you have URLs that return errors. During your site crawl, you should identify and fix any URLs that return errors (this also includes soft 404 errors). If a broken URL's corresponding page is no longer available on your site, redirect the URL to a relevant replacement. Speaking of redirection, this is also a great opportunity to inventory your site's redirection techniques. Be sure the site is using 301 HTTP redirects (and not 302 HTTP redirects, meta refresh redirects, or JavaScript-based redirects) because they pass the most link juice to their destination pages.
- Your site's **[XML Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en)** provides a roadmap for search engine crawlers to ensure they can easily find all of your site's pages.
- Your **[website architecture](https://www.w3.org/standards/webarch/)** defines the overall structure of your website, including its vertical depth (how many levels it has) as well as its horizontal breadth at each level. When evaluating your site architecture, identify how many clicks it takes to get from the homepage to other important pages - recommend a maximum of 3 clicks.
- **Flash and JavaScript Navigation**. The best site architecture in the world can be undermined by navigational elements that are inaccessible to search engines. Although search engine crawlers have become much more intelligent over the years, it is still safer to avoid Flash and JavaScript navigation.
- Site Performance. Users have a very limited attention span, and if your website takes too long to load, they will leave. Similarly, search engine crawlers have a limited amount of time that they can allocate to each site on the Internet. Tools: **[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)** + **[Webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)** (more detailed).

Indexability. We need to determine how many of those pages are actually being indexed by the search engines.

- You can use the **[operator](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)** "site:" to get a very rough estimate for the number of pages that are being indexed by a given search engine.
- Check the availability and indexing of each web page with the operator "info:"

Source: the article **[How to Perform the World's Greatest SEO Audit](https://moz.com/blog/how-to-perform-the-worlds-greatest-seo-audit)**.

Please note that Google provides it directly to you. Search Console provides lots of information regarding how the search engine views your website — from the number of pages indexed and whether Google has found malware to 404 page errors and issues regarding title/meta description tags.

**Verify your website in Google’s Search Console**. To access this information, you have to first verify your website.

**Review the relevant reports**. The Search Console includes information from the following reports: 
 - *Search Appearance → HTML improvements*. 
 - *Search Traffic → Manual Actions*. 
 - *Search Traffic → Mobile Usability*. 
 - *Google Index → Index Status*.

**Crawl → Crawl Errors**. This is the report tells you how many 404 “Not Found” pages Google has discovered.

**Crawl → Site Map**. For this report, we look for any warnings from Google — typically warnings that pages within the website can’t be crawled or other issues.

**Security**. This report shows if Google has detected any malware on your website.

Source: [**How to determine if that ‘free audit’ solicitation email is legit**](http://searchengineland.com/determine-free-audit-solicitation-email-legit-277833).